# Menu item fail to show what is in CSS

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<td class="style22" align="center">

    <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Items>
            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/>
            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About"/>
        </Items>
    </asp:Menu>

&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">




div.menu
{
    padding: 4px 0px 4px 8px;
}

div.menu ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: auto;
}

div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited
{
    background-color: #465c71;
    border: 1px #4e667d solid;
    color: #dde4ec;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.35em;
    padding: 4px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div.menu ul li a:hover
{
    background-color: #bfcbd6;
    color: #465c71;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.menu ul li a:active
{
    background-color: #465c71;
    color: #cfdbe6;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific about what the problem is.

Comment: if i edit my css and stuff it will not change my menu

Comment: for the benefit of those of us who don't remember exactly how an asp:Menu renders to HTML can you post the actual HTML generated as well as the ASPX mark up?  Please edit your question (rather than adding in comments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change div.menu to .menu

```
.menu
{
    padding: 4px 0px 4px 8px;
}

.menu ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: auto;
}

.menu ul li a, .menu ul li a:visited
{
    background-color: #465c71;
    border: 1px #4e667d solid;
    color: #dde4ec;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.35em;
    padding: 4px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.menu ul li a:hover
{
    background-color: #bfcbd6;
    color: #465c71;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu ul li a:active
{
    background-color: #465c71;
    color: #cfdbe6;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because your .Net Framework renders asp:MenuItem as Table.

You can change the renderingmode to `list` and the problem will be solved.

To change your renderingMode you must add:

```
RenderingMode="List"
```

to `<Asp:Menu>`Tag Like This:

```
    <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal" RenderingMode="List">
```